# Why fread() throwing the 'segmentation fault' in this code

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fread

The program is to check raw file and identify jpg files. also raw file is formatted as FAT and therefore I must check it as 512 Byte chunks.

I made (?) 512 Bytes memory space with `BYTE fats[512];` and used is in `fread()` as target memory slot, but in this process it throwing 'segmentation fault' error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *dmgdFile = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (dmgdFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char name[7];
    int counter = 0;
    int discovered = 0;
    FILE *outptr;
    BYTE fats[512];

    sprintf(name, "%03d.jpg", discovered);//name regeneration

    while (fread(&fats, sizeof(fats), 1, dmgdFile)){
        if (
            discovered > 0 &&  //DISCOVERED ANOTHER JPG
            fats[0] == 0xff &&
            fats[1] == 0xd8 &&
            fats[2] == 0xff &&
            fats[3] >= 0xe0 && fats[3] <= 0xef) {

            printf("repeated discovery");
            fclose(outptr);
            sprintf(name, "%03d.jpg", discovered);//name regeneration

            outptr = fopen(name, "w");  //create next jpg file and open pointer
            if (outptr == NULL)
            {
                fclose(dmgdFile);
                fprintf(stderr, "Could not create %s.\n", name);
                return 5;
            }

            counter ++;
            discovered ++;


        } else if(discovered > 0){                  //ADDING JPG BODY TO PREVIOUS OPENED FILE
            printf("body");
            fwrite(fats, sizeof(fats), 1, outptr);
            counter ++;
        }else if (
            discovered == 0 &&  //FIRST TIME DISCOVERING JPG HEADER
            fats[0] == 0xff &&
            fats[1] == 0xd8 &&
            fats[2] == 0xff &&
            fats[3] >= 0xe0 && fats[3] <= 0xef) {

            printf("1st time discovered");
            outptr = fopen(name, "w");
            if (outptr == NULL)
            {
                fclose(dmgdFile);
                fprintf(stderr, "Could not create %s.\n", name);
                return 5;
            }

            fwrite(fats, sizeof(fats), 1, outptr);


            counter ++;
            discovered ++;
        }
    }
    fclose(dmgdFile);
}
```

I tried fats with and without '&' in 'fread()' but it didn't helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sprintf(name, "%03d.jpg", discovered);
```

will write a string with at least 7 charactes to `name`, but the array `name` has only 7 elements. This will lead to out-of-range access, considering the terminating null-character. It looks like this out-of-range access broke the file pointer and lead to Segmentation Fault.

Allocate enough element and use [`snprintf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) to avoid buffer overrun like this:

```
char name[32];

snprintf(name, sizeof(name), "%03d.jpg", discovered);
```